# Magento media url getting messed up

Tags: magento-1.9, php

```
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Sizing/NfI6375.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
```

This how it should be, but what it looks like the frontend is:

```
<p><img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" sizing="" nfi6375.png"}}"="" alt=""></p>
```

This the Code for that specific attribute, that works like the description.

```
<div id="size-chart" > <?php echo $_product->getData('sizechartadvanced') ?></div>
```

Comment: Where you are calling this? In CMS block or CMS page ?

Comment: Does it make any difference? it's in the product description.

Comment: Check admin -> system -> configuration -> Catalog (Left side) -> Frontend ->  Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories (last field)  -> Set value to Yes. 
If it is already set to yes, show me your code how you are displaying product description

Comment: What do you mean how i'm showing the code??.. i've added the product phtml file

Comment: Looks like you are calling it in `.phtml` file, if that's the case this wont work.

Comment: So don't you have solution? isn't product description allow this? and it has been called that view.phtml.. so why this won't work? make sense!

Comment: I ask you to show code because sometime people call it like $_product->getDescription(); but it must be called in way like echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description'); But as you said it's default view.phtml than it should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Custom attribute with wysiwyg cannot be simply outputted.

If it contains cms directives {{media url="wysiwyg/images_2_.jpg"}}, it should be preprocessed with catalog/output helper.

```
<?php
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $attribute = $product->getYourAttribute();
    $attributeName = 'your_attribute_name';
    echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($product, $attribute, $attributeName);
?>
```

Important

Check that in sql upgrade your custom attribute was created correctly with all necessary properties

```
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_attribute', array(
    'group'                    => 'General',
    'input'                    => 'textarea',
    'type'                     => 'text',
    'label'                    => 'Custom attribute',
    'backend'                  => '',
    'visible'                  => true,
    'required'                 => false,
    'visible_on_front'         => true,
    'global'                   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'wysiwyg_enabled'          => true,
    //these attribute is very important for processing cms directives
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
));
```

Also make sure that "Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories" in System->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend is set to "yes".

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

There seems problem with handling "" double quotes. Try using single quotes inside double quotes `<p><img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/Sizing/NfI6375.png'}}" alt="" /></p>`.

Some time we face such situations where we have to use double quotes inside double quotes then you should negate its impact using the code like `<p><img src="{{media url=\"wysiwyg/Sizing/NfI6375.png\"}}" alt="" /></p>`

Hope it will help you out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call image that is in `media` folder from `.phtml` file then should use this way:

**Calling in `.phtml` file:**

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') ?>wysiwyg/Sizing/NfI6375.png.jpg">
```

If this doesn't work try this one:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) ?>wysiwyg/Sizing/NfI6375.png.jpg">
```

As I understand your question your `NfI6375.png` is located in `media > wysiwyg > Sizing` folder.

**Calling in CMS page**

```
<p><img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/Sizing/NfI6375.png'}}" alt="" /></p>
```

As Lapitsphp suggested, it's your `"` playing the role. Change it to single quotation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: WELL this won't work.. because i'm calling the attribute which is text/html field.. and from product page i insert the image and save as any description.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> ```
> $value = "<p><img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/Sizing/NfI6375.png'}}" alt="" /></p>";
> ```
>
> `$processedValue = Mage::helper("cms")->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($value);`